# Value of vec3 in an object

Tags: c++

I have the following code :

main.cpp :

```
Camera camera(cam_position, cam_front, world_up, i);
cout << camera.cam_position.x << " " << camera.cam_position.y << " " << camera.cam_front.z << " : "<<i<<endl;
```

And my class Camera :

```
class Camera
{
private:
    glm::vec3 world_up;
public:
    glm::vec3 cam_front;
    glm::vec3 cam_position;
    glm::mat4x4 view_matrix;
    float i;

    Camera(glm::vec3 cam_position = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f),
        glm::vec3 cam_front = glm::vec3(0.f, 0.f, 1.f),
        glm::vec3 world_up = glm::vec3(0.f, 1.f, 0.f),
        float i=2);

    //Send view_matrix to the shaders
    void UpdateCamera(GLuint& core_program);

    glm::vec3 GetCameraPosition() const;
    glm::mat4x4 GetViewMatrix() const;

};

Camera::Camera(glm::vec3 cam_position ,
    glm::vec3 cam_front,
    glm::vec3 world_up,
    float i
)
{

    view_matrix = glm::mat4x4(1.f);
    view_matrix = glm::lookAt(cam_position, cam_position + cam_front, world_up);
    cout << cam_position.x << ":" << cam_position.y << ":" << cam_position.z << ":"<<i<<endl;

}
```

When I instantiate my camera object in main.cpp, my print inside my constructor output this :

> 0:0:2:5

And the print just after the instantiation of camera is :

> -1.07374e+08 -1.07374e+08 -1.07374e+08 : 5

Why does the value of my vec3 is close to 0 for xyz? And my float i has the same value?

Anwser :  I corrected my constructor with this->cam_position = cam_position, etc...

Comment: Try to [explain your constructor to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). And remember that inside the constructor, `cam_position` is the *local argument* with that name.

Comment: thanks, for some reasonI though default value in my constructor were applying to my members variables... 
But I corrected my constructor with this->cam_position = cam_position, etc...

Comment: Is it solved now? If so please post an answer and validate it.